# Automatically running an ST_AsText query over multiple rows in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, geometry, well-known-text

After my SpatiaLite database got corrupted, I used a recovery tool to recover what was lost. I now do have the database, but I can't visualise the features on a map.

I figured out that with `SELECT ST_AsText(x'*HEX-number*')` I get the 'Well Known Text' variant of my geometry. This would be enough for me: I will use a Python script to make a shapefile out of this.

However, I have 12k + rows that have to be transformed and my knowledge of SQL is too limited to automate this. If I look at my recovered table in QGIS, I have the following situation:

[image]

The geometry column shows the hexdecimal number, which, with the ST_AsText function transforms into a LINESTRINGS and POLYGONS.

[image]

How can I automate this over all 12k+ rows, so that I'd fill the 'Geometry_WKT' column with this?

In Python, I'd do something like this:

```
for row in table:
    row[11] = ST_AsText("x'{}'".format(row[10]))
```

How to do this in SQL?

Comment: It seems to me that you have correct SpatiaLite binary geometries in the table and you should just register the field into the database so that QGIS understands that there is a geometry column. If that is the case one SQL command `recovergeometrycolumn` would do it https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

Comment: Shapefile is a poor choice to recover SQLite data, since it truncates column names, reduces datetime resolution, truncates strings past 254 length, and corrupts numeric NULLs.

Comment: A shapefile is what my client needs. It only needs to contain the information from column 'Type_schad' and show where this feature is located ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query.

```sql
select *, st_astext(geometry) as geometry_wkt
from myLayer
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need, however: It just returns NULL. Even if I modify it such that is also takes the "x'" and the ' at the end. I ended up with: 
select *, ST_AsText("x" || CHAR(39) || Geometry || CHAR(39)) as Geometry_WKT from recovered